# React native app with Amplify. Send Push notification

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I am refering this site -https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/push-notifications/getting-started/q/platform/react-native/ and I am not sure how I can send a push notification to other users from react native.

I am able to send a test from aws pinpoint with token which was logged into the device. What I want to implement is sending a push notification to another user from the app. Should I save all user's token into database? or is there an API to get any user's APN&FCM token?

Could I have some guidance for this?